# Resize an image bigger than available RAM

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I have a basic php script to dynamically resize images on my (virtual shared) server using [GD](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php) and serve them up as required.

Unfortunately, following the purchase of a better camera with [more megapixels](https://www.xkcd.com/1014/), the script falls over due to lack of memory (my hosting allocates ~50m and an *uncompressed* 20Mpix image is over that limit).

Note that *uncompressed* means any image file that is loaded with one of:

```
imageCreateFromGif($filepath);
imageCreateFromJpeg($filepath);
imageCreateFromPng($filepath);
imageCreateFromBmp($filepath);
```

As these convert the file into the full-resolution raw image data in full 8-bit-per-pixel plus alpha in memory for further processing.

I can detect the image is oversize using `getimagesize()` and gracefully refuse to load it, but it would be nice to be able to handle these larger images without busting the RAM limit.

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

The server is a cheap shared commercial hosting package so I can't do anything about the restrictions on RAM or change the PHP runtime config or things like that.

Comment: Seriously, in the days of DigitalOcean and stuff like that, use another hosting provider. Computing power today is quite abundant and cheap.

Comment: Use Imagick, you can specify a RAM limit and if Imagick hits the limit, it will "save" the rest on the HDD.

Comment: You can almost certainly get a result with **vips** which is very frugal on memory - try searching on SO.

Comment: Thanks guys. @iSS - I'm aware other providers are available but let's assume that's a whole load of ball-ache for the sake of one image resizing script.